# proper base change theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $f: X \to S$ be proper with $S$ the spectrum of a stricly henselian DVR and $X_0$ the special and $X_1$ the generic fibre. Why do we have $H^q(X,F) = H^q(X_0,F)$, but not $H^q(X,F) = H^q(X_1,F)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand this sort of question, you should begin by first understanding the case
when $S$ is the open unit disk in $\mathbb C$, and $X$ is a proper family of varieties.

For example, let $X$ be the family of conics $xy - t = 0$.  (Here I am writing
the family of affine curves, but I really mean the corresponding family of projective
curves.)

If $t$ is non-zero, the fibre $X_t$ is a smooth conic, hence homeomorphic to a $2$-sphere.

If $t = 0$, then the fibre $X_t$ is a pair of lines meeting at a point, so homeomorphic to the gluing of two $2$-spheres along a common point.

Can you see that these have different cohomology?  Perhaps you can also prove 
that $X$ retracts onto $X_0$, and so has cohomology isomorphic to $X_0$ (and
so *not* isomorphic to $X_1$).

---

Perhaps you also have a technical question about why proper base-change implies one statement and not the other?  If you confirm this, I can try to explain.  But in the meantime, I suggest trying to build some intuition about the whole context by looking at simple examples of the kind described above.